# Chown command usage in perl script

Tags: linux, perl, chown

I couldn't find any information about -1 usage in below row in Perl scripting.

```
chown -1, $group, $directory
```

Answer (score 5):

[`perldoc -f chown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html):

> chown LIST
>
> Changes the owner (and group) of a list of files. The first two
>   elements of the list must be the numeric uid and gid, in that order. **A
>   value of -1 in either position is interpreted by most systems to leave
>   that value unchanged**. Returns the number of files successfully
>   changed.
>
> ```
> my $cnt = chown $uid, $gid, 'foo', 'bar';
> chown $uid, $gid, @filenames;
> ```
>
> ...